# typescript: declare module exports?

Tags: typescript

How can i declare that a ts file or files exports some methods?

For example there is a es6 file `toyota.ts`

```
export const turnLeft: number = (param1: string, param2: number) => {
  // do it...
}
export const turnRight: number = (param1: string, param2: number) => {
  // do it...
}
```

A second es6 file `honda.ts`

```
export const turnLeft: number = (param1: string, param2: number) => {
  // do it...
}
export const turnRight: number = (param1: string, param2: number) => {
  // do it...
}
```

How can i make a type file which describes both these ts files.
i.e. declare that the file has two exports which are called turnLeft and turnRight.

So that if I have a third file `nissan.ts` and it only has turnLeft, then when I do `tsc` it will tell me the error?

I have tried to enforce the `toyota.ts` by making a `toyota.d.ts` file with `declare` in it. But when `tsc -w` runs it does not even reload when i change the `toyota.d.ts`. Having the `toyota.d.ts` did nothing. So i could not even get the first step of getting one of the js file's exports to be checked, let alone all 3 files checked using the same declaration.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It feels like you are approaching this incorrectly. What about using classes? All these cars extend from a base class with public methods, and some cars have additional methods that the base class dont.

Comment: yeah, i know that option. i want to do it without making class and interface.

Comment: Don’t think that’s how typescript and type declaration files work. How does this approach has any advantage over a class-based one? And with classes you get implicit typing.

Comment: i dont want to use classes and object oriented programming.

Comment: conceptually, what i am trying to do is to implement interface without having to make my files honda.js/toyota.js/nissan.js be class definitions. Is there some kind of way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: Not without objects/classes. That’s the whole point.

Comment: Thanks @Terry. Eventually, i've come to the same conclusion and wrote the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it seems there is no way to do this at this time.

It is being discussed in a number of open issues without resolution yet.

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38511

In the end, there seems no way to declare interface which is then used to type check a module to see what it exports.
The closest way is to implement a class in the module which contains all the exports and make that class implement that interface.